# Why doesn't `reduce` evaluate the block for single element arrays?

Tags: ruby, reduce

I was experimenting on ruby's `reduce` method, which is a great tool for enumerables manipulation.

I had a hard time understanding why the below is returning a string rather than an integer when the array contains  a single element:

```
["1", "2"].reduce { |sum, i| sum.to_i + i.to_i }
#=> 3 <- expected

["1"].reduce { |sum, i| sum.to_i + i.to_i }
#=> "1" <- not expected, expecting it to be 1
```

while the below work as expected:

```
["1"].reduce(0) { |sum, i| sum.to_i + i.to_i }
#=> 1
```

I know that I'm initializing the accumulator with value 0 in this case, but I'm curious why the former implementation does not work!

Comment: I've simplified your example a bit. The assignment to `sum` in the block wasn't necessary.

Comment: Thanks @Stefan looks better :)

Comment: In the last example it's sufficient to convert `i`, i.e. `sum + i.to_i` – the accumulator `sum` is already numeric.

Answer (score 5):

Well, I believe I have found an explanation. It seems that reduce will not enter the block iteration defined in reduce method, as it already took the first element as an accumulator thus the array is left empty, and no further work is needed, that's why the element will return as is.

Which makes total sense! as otherwise the accumulator will be counted twice.

Comment: Yep, that was it.

Comment: Indeed, you can't apply a binary operation to a single element.

Answer (score 2):

The last one works because you give reduce an accumulator starting value and then it starts iterating. If you don't give it one it takes the first element of the sequence (array in this case or anything enumerable) and then it has nothing left to iterate over, so the block is never called.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but well, that sucks. I just fixed a bug in production due to this behavior.